# php laravel Auth::check is not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel

In my `HomeController`, the `Auth::attempt()` function is working perfect, and also `Auth::user()` array values are printed successfully.

If the problem is the `Auth` function is not working in my `ViewListController`, but I specified needed classes in my `ViewListController`.

---

In my `HomeController.php` `PostLogin` function :

```
if(Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
    print_r(Auth::user());exit;
    return redirect('inbox');
} else{
    return redirect('login');
}
```

In my `ViewListController.php` `GetListView` function :

```
if(Auth::check()){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failed";
}
```

> Output: Failed.

Any idea how I can fix this?!

Comment: If you `exit` prematurely, the application teardown is never executed properly and your `Auth::attempt()` will only work for that single request. If you want to exit without rendering the view, try `print_r(Auth::user()); return;` instead to ensure that the User session is set properly.

Comment: You have someone error on page? Mayby you need add on top Use Auth;

Comment: I used Use Auth; and my page did display any error always it will go to else part

Comment: `print_r(Auth::user());exit; ` comment this statement and try. If you want to check the user is logged in ViewListController then Auth::check() is not the best way to do you can use middleware.

Comment: print_r(Auth::user());exit;  i  already tried this it will return null , nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line :

```
print_r(Auth::user());exit;
```

So, basically, replace this ...

```
if(Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
    print_r(Auth::user());exit;
    return redirect('inbox');
} else{
    return redirect('login');
}
```

... with this :

```
if(Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
    // print_r(Auth::user());exit;
    return redirect('inbox');
} else{
    return redirect('login');
}
```

That line looks like debug code someone put there and forgot to remove.

Anyway, [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) ALWAYS terminates execution of the script whenever it is called. That means that **anything** that comes after exit is completely ignored. See [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).